# Return the first "n" count of characters of a string ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript

I've used this :

```
String.Prototype.left = function left(count){
   return this.substr(0,count);
}
```

And apply it this way :

```
var string = "Hello Stack!";
console.log(string.left(5));
```

And the console tells me :

```
TypeError: example.left is not a function
console.log(example.left(5));
```

How can I fix it? And where is the problem?

Comment: Prototype, typo. * `prototype`, case sensitive

Comment: Odd there is no *Cannot set 'left' of undefined* if thats the case

Comment: And of course your code uses the name `string` while the error message says something about `example`, which suggest that you're not getting that exception from the code you've shown.

Comment: @Bergi - I'm guessing that the OP is following an example from somewhere, made the typo, and the `example` error is from what they actually tried while the `string` variable name is from the example itself.

Comment: Can somebody delete the topic.Im very sorry about the off-topic.I'm new to stackoverflow,I didn't make it to farm points,I use this site only in еxtreme conditions : ) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
String.prototype.left = function(index){
  return this.substring(0,index);
}

var str = "Hello World";

console.log(str.left(5));
```

Comment: A) An explanation should always be in your answer, not just a code dump. B) if you believe the problem to be a typo, flag the question as off-topic instead of trying to farm rep from it.

Comment: There is no need for explanation to this answer. Its just typo.

Comment: Excuse me.I didn't know that this is type of a off-topic.Can somebody delete this topic ?